# Supplementary material for "Survival and Event History Analysis, A Process Point of View" by Aalen et al

Tags: self-study, survival, references

I am doing a self study of "Survival and Event History Analysis" by Aalen et al. Overall, I like the book. It is my second pass at survival analysis (I used
Survival analysis: Techniques for censored and truncated data by Klein and Moeschberger). This is a nice dive into the underlying theory without needing to revisit measure theory first (they wave their hand at it, but don't require you to know it well).

Can anyone recommend some supplementary material? Specifically, video lectures would be really useful. Alternatively, if a professor has some notes they used for a similar class or a class that used the book.